# How to pass parameters to function without calling function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm trying to find a way to get a function requiring a parameter without actually calling the function.

Current broken code example:

```
const _validations = {
  userID: (req) => check('userID').isString().isUUID('4').run(req),
};

async function (req, res, next) {
  const allReqFields = { ...req.body, ...req.params, ...req.query };

  const fieldsFound = [];
  for (let key of Object.keys(allReqFields)) {
    if (_.has(_validations, key)) {
      fieldsFound.push(_validations[key](req));
    }
  }

  await Promise.all(fieldsFound);

  return next();
},
  function (req, res, next) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
//ALWAYS HITS HERE
      return next();
    }else{}
}
```

Code example that works but I don't want:

```
const _validations = {
  userID: (req) => check('userID').isString().isUUID('4').run(req),
};

async function (req, res, next) {
  const allReqFields = { ...req.body, ...req.params, ...req.query };

  for (let key of Object.keys(allReqFields)) {
    if (_.has(_validations, key)) {
      await _validations[key](req);
    }
  }


  return next();
},
  function (req, res, next) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
//Correctly hits here
      return next();
    }else{
//Correctly hits here
    }
}
```

For some context:

The function `(req) => check('userID').isString().isUUID('4').run(req),` returns a promise.

There are going to be more keys/values inside the `_validations` object.

Every function inside of `_validations` will require `req` to be passed to it.

The end goal is to run all those async functions while having req passed to them.

**The issue I'm having now is that `fieldsFound.push(_validations[key](req));` is pushing a promise and not the function for me to call later. Which means that `fieldsFound` is an array of unresolved promises**

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you explain "The end goal is to run all those async functions while having req passed to them." in different words?

Comment: @SteveBennett I went ahead and added the issue I'm having. Does that help at all?

Comment: Why not `fieldsFound.push(_validations[key])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const _validations = {
  userID: () => check('userID').isString().isUUID('4'),
};
```

Then you push the functions without calling them:

```
fieldsFound.push(_validations[key]);
```

And then at the end just call each one with `req` and await the promises returned:

```
await Promise.all(fieldsFound.map(func => func().run(req));
```

Comment: It's not in scope. I went ahead and updating my post!

Comment: @DanMossa can't you just run `.run(req)` at the end?

Comment: Say more? Where would I be putting the `.run(req)` ?

Comment: I don't want a foreach, or else I would just be `await _validations[key](req);` . I want these to be fired all at once.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve then?
`await Promise.all(fieldsFound.map(func => func().run(req));`

Comment: Glad to hear. Updated to the final form.

Comment: Even simpler, build `_validations` as Array, not Object, in the first place.

Comment: Why remove `.run(req)` from the functions and add it back in the `.map()` callback? What would happen if each of the validation calls was differently composed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function currying.

> Currying is a process in functional programming in which we can transform a function 
>   with multiple arguments into a sequence of nesting functions. It returns a new function 
>   that expects the next argument inline.

Transform your function to something like this.

```
const _validations = {
  userID: (req) => () => check('userID').isString().isUUID('4').run(req),
};
```

So you can invoke the function later.

Comment: Interesting! Never heard of it before. I updated my code but this doesn't seem to work?

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: When I do it with individual awaits, the function gets called correctly because there's another line that checks to see if there were errors and that doesn't get called. I'll update my original post for explanation

Comment: As you mentioned in the question, Using above method you can push the functions to the array. eg : `fieldsFound.push(_validations[key](req));`. So you can call those functions later with the req you passed before.